# How to remove all balise in text python

Tags: python, python-3.x, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I want to extract data from a tag to simply retrieve the text. Unfortunately I can't extract just the text, I always have links in this one.

Is it possible to remove all of the `<img>` and `<a href>` tags from my text?

```
<div class="xxx" data-handler="xxx">its a good day
<a class="link" href="https://" title="text">https:// link</a></div>
```

I just want to recover this : `its a good day` and ignore the content of the `<a href>` tag in my `<div>` tag

Currently I perform the extraction via a `beautifulsoup.find('div)`

Comment: what does your code look like - minimal reproducible example ?

Answer (score 1):

Try to do this

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

#response = requests.get('your url')

html = BeautifulSoup('''<div class="xxx" data-handler="xxx">its a good day
<a class="link" href="https://" title="text">https:// link</a> 
</div>''', 'html.parser')

soup = html.find_all(class_='xxx')

print(soup[0].text.split('\n')[0])
```

Comment: Welcome to SO and thanks for first answer - Improving it, may take a minute or two to read: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Take a closer look at your example it do not fit the OPs needs cause it is not providing text before `<a>` only. It also throws an error, so removing unnecessary parts would improve the example code. Some explanation would also be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

##### EDIT

Based on your comment, that all text before `<a>` should be captured and not only the first one in element, select all `previous_siblings` and check for [`NavigableString`](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#navigablestring):

```
' '.join(
    [s for s in soup.select_one('.xxx a').previous_siblings if isinstance(s, NavigableString)]
)
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import Tag, NavigableString, BeautifulSoup

html='''
<div class="xxx" data-handler="xxx"><br>New wallpaper <br>Find over 100+ of <a class="link" href="https://" title="text">https:// link</a></div>
'''
soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

' '.join(
    [s for s in soup.select_one('.xxx a').previous_siblings if isinstance(s, NavigableString)]
)
```

---

To focus just on the text and not the children tags of an element, you could use :

```
.find(text=True)
```

In case the pattern is always the same and text the first part of [content](https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#contents-and-children) in the element:

```
.contents[0]
```

##### Example

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
html='''
<div class="xxx" data-handler="xxx">its a good day
<a class="link" href="https://" title="text">https:// link</a></div>
'''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html)

soup.div.find(text=True).strip()
```

##### Output

```
its a good day
```

Comment: Thanks for the tips, this seems to match my search but I get stuck if I have links in the div.

In this example:
<div data-handler=" class="xxx">
<br>New wallpaper
<br>Find over 100+ of
<a href="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1622640.jpg" title="https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1622640.jpg">https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1622640.jpg </a>>
</div>


I would like to have the result:
new wallpaper
Find over 100+ of 

I have the last text that is visible at the a href tag:
https://wallpaperaccess.com/full/1622640.jpg

Comment: This should be part of your question to clarify as in the moment the question is misleading. Check the edit in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

Let's import `re` and use `re.sub`:

```
import re 

s1 = '<div class="xxx" data-handler="xxx">its a good day'
s2 = '<a class="link" href="https://" title="text">https:// link</a></div>'
    
    
s1 = re.sub(r'\<[^()]*\>', '', s1)
s2 = re.sub(r'\<[^()]*\>', '', s2)
```

**Output**

```
>>> print(s1)
... 'its a good day'
>>> print(s2)
... ''
```

Answer (score 0):

So basically you don't want any text inside the `<a>` tags and everything within all tags.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

html1='''
<div class="xxx" data-handler="xxx"><br>New wallpaper <br>Find over 100+ of <a class="link" href="https://" title="text">https:// link </a></div>
'''
html2 = ''' <div class="xxx" data-handler="xxx">its a good day
<a class="link" href="https://" title="text">https:// link</a></div> '''

html3 = ''' <div class="xxx" data-handler="xxx"><br>New wallpaper <br>Find over 100+ of <a class="link" href="https://" title="text">https:// link </a><div class="xxx" data-handler="xxx">its a good day
<a class="link" href="https://" title="text">https:// link</a></div></div> '''

soup = BeautifulSoup(html3,'html.parser')


for t in soup.find_all('a', href=True):
    t.decompose()
test = soup.find('div',class_='xxx').getText().strip()

print(test)
```

output:

```
#for html1: New wallpaper Find over 100+ of
#for html2: its a good day
#for html3: New wallpaper Find over 100+ of its a good day
```